# nginx: decrypting a query param

Tags: nginx

I have 2 servers. Server A is a Windows server running ASP.NET, and server B is a Linux server running Nginx. I need to redirect a user from Server A to Server B securely. I would like to have Server A encrypt a value like `ip=132.65.78.4;user=xyz@example.com;node=abc` into a query parameter of a redirect like this: `https://serverb.example.com?encrypted=<encrypted value here>`

Then have Server B (using a shared secret) decrypt the query param, validate the IP address the user is coming from, and then trust the values of `user` and `node` to process the request.

How can I configure `nginx` to do this? I can figure out the Server A part myself based on the answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend making use of the "nginx lua" module, which will let you modify portions of the request with Lua code.

There are facilities in there to specifically modify the query string, so you can perform your encryption and set the "encrypted" value.

https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxreqset_uri_args

In the case where you want to process request arguments, you can do this via a `set_by_lua_block` or `set_by_lua_file`

So perhaps you might do something like:

```
set_by_lua_block $validated {
   local enc = ngx.var.arg_encrypted
   local decrypted = decrypt(enc)

   return do_some_validation(decrypted) and "1" or "0"
}

if ($validated = "0") {
   return 403;
}
```

Comment: Thx! My goal is for the nginx side to only have to _decrypt_ the encrypted message. Would I still use "nginx lua" for that?

Comment: Edited my answer with a proposal along those lines